# CSS displays wrong on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
.foot-1, .foot-2, .foot-3 .foot-4 {
float: left;
width: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
min-width: 25%;
}

.foot-1 {

}

.foot-2 {

}

.foot-3 {

}

.foot-4 {

}

.boxesFooterBoxes .box {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.boxesFooterBoxes .boxContainer {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I Added this Code to my Website to Display my boxes in a row the right way and it works, but on smaller screens browsers keep sueeze the boxes into one another.

What can i do to imrpove my code and make my boxes fit smaller devices?

Website for testing: https://www.alpaka-industries.de

Comment: Have you tried to use media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) ?

Comment: Have a look at media queries

Comment: I did, but it doesnt work fo me

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to use custom css for different screen widths

`@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
 }`

Comment: Then I best suggest you use a responsive framework. Like [materialize](http://materializecss.com) or [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrap for responsiveness of your website open link below:

[Global CSS settings, fundamental HTML elements styled and enhanced with extensible classes, and an advanced grid system.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/)